# Parsing XML with XPath and adding the required fields to a list

Tags: java, xml, parsing, path

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bins>
        <bin>
            <number>100510</number>
            <brand>LOCAL CARD</brand>
            <bank></bank>
            <type></type>
            <level></level>
            <isocountry>UNITED KINGDOM</isocountry>
            <info></info>
            <country_iso>GB</country_iso>
            <country2_iso>GBR</country2_iso>
            <country3_iso>826</country3_iso>
            <www>NULL</www>
            <phone>NULL</phone>
            <former_bank>NULL</former_bank>
            <address>NULL</address>
        </bin>
        <bin>
            <number>100515</number>
            <brand>LOCAL CARD</brand>
            <bank></bank>
            <type></type>
            <level></level>
            <isocountry>NORWAY</isocountry>
            <info></info>
            <country_iso>NO</country_iso>
            <country2_iso>NOR</country2_iso>
            <country3_iso>578</country3_iso>
            <www>NULL</www>
            <phone>NULL</phone>
            <former_bank>NULL</former_bank>
            <address>NULL</address>
        </bin>
        <bin>
            <number>103753</number>
            <brand>LOCAL CARD</brand>
            <bank>I&amp;M BANK</bank>
            <type>DEBIT</type>
            <level>PREPAID</level>
            <isocountry>KENYA</isocountry>
            <info></info>
            <country_iso>KE</country_iso>
            <country2_iso>KEN</country2_iso>
            <country3_iso>404</country3_iso>
            <www></www>
            <phone></phone>
            <former_bank>NULL</former_bank>
            <address>NULL</address>
        </bin>
        <bin>
            <number>104001</number>
            <brand>LOCAL CARD</brand>
            <bank>LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS</bank>
            <type></type>
            <level></level>
            <isocountry>CANADA</isocountry>
            <info></info>
            <country_iso>CA</country_iso>
            <country2_iso>CAN</country2_iso>
            <country3_iso>124</country3_iso>
            <www></www>
            <phone></phone>
            <former_bank></former_bank>
            <address></address>
        </bin>
        </bins>
```

Code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public abstract class XMLDataParser extends FileParser {
    public static DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    List<String> binList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<String>> binDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public List<List<String>> parseFile(String fileContent) throws IOException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression1 = xpath.compile("//bins/*");
        Object result1 = xPathExpression1.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        XPathExpression xPathExpression2 = xpath.compile("//bins//bin//*/text()");
        Object result2 = xPathExpression2.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) result1;
        NodeList nodeList2 = (NodeList) result2;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {
                        binList.add(nodeList2.item(j).getNodeValue());
                    }
                binDataList.add(binList);
            }
        System.out.println(binList);

        return binDataList;
    }
}
```

Output

> [[100510, LOCAL CARD, UNITED KINGDOM, GB, GBR, 826, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, 100515, LOCAL CARD, NORWAY, NO, NOR, 578, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, 103753, LOCAL CARD, I&M BANK, DEBIT, PREPAID, KENYA, KE, KEN,
>   404, NULL, NULL, 104001, LOCAL CARD, LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) -
>   TDFS, CANADA, CA, CAN, 124, 100510, LOCAL CARD, UNITED KINGDOM, GB,
>   GBR, 826, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 100515, LOCAL CARD, NORWAY, NO, NOR,
>   578, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 103753, LOCAL CARD, I&M BANK, DEBIT,
>   PREPAID, KENYA, KE, KEN, 404, NULL, NULL, 104001, LOCAL CARD, LUXURY
>   JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS, CANADA, CA, CAN, 124, 100510, LOCAL
>   CARD, UNITED KINGDOM, GB, GBR, 826, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 100515,
>   LOCAL CARD, NORWAY, NO, NOR, 578, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 103753,
>   LOCAL CARD, I&M BANK, DEBIT, PREPAID, KENYA, KE, KEN, 404, NULL, NULL,
>   104001, LOCAL CARD, LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS, CANADA, CA,
>   CAN, 124, 100510, LOCAL CARD, UNITED KINGDOM, GB, GBR, 826, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, 100515, LOCAL CARD, NORWAY, NO, NOR, 578, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, 103753, LOCAL CARD, I&M BANK, DEBIT, PREPAID, KENYA,
>   KE, KEN, 404, NULL, NULL, 104001, LOCAL CARD, LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS
>   (LJC) - TDFS, CANADA, CA, CAN, 124]]

I need a output as

> [[100510, LOCAL CARD, UNITED KINGDOM, GB, GBR, 826, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL], [100515, LOCAL CARD, NORWAY, NO, NOR, 578, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL] ,[103753, LOCAL CARD, I&M BANK, DEBIT, PREPAID, KENYA, KE, KEN,
>   404, NULL, NULL], [104001, LOCAL CARD, LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) -
>   TDFS, CANADA, CA, CAN, 124]]

But, I am not able to get this. Please provide a solution.
I have to use Xpath to get this output.

Comment: @sanjeev > it looks like the OP already did most of the work and shares his code with us, the output he gets is close to the expected one so I guess it's just a matter of finding where exactly he failed... I guess though, cause i'm no Java developer :-) I'm voting to leave this open...

Comment: @LaurentS. Agree with you.. I missed the java code OP Posted below XML and it was not visible earlier. I also retracted my close vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the 2nd XPath to be relative to `bin` returned by the 1st XPath. Also, you'd need a different `ArrayList` instance to for each `bin`, so `binList` needs to be declared in the scope of the outer loop. I am not Java developer, but I think it should about like this :

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression1 = xpath.compile("//bins/*");
Object result1 = xPathExpression1.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) result1;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
    XPathExpression xPathExpression2 = xpath.compile("*/text()");
    Object result2 = xPathExpression2.evaluate(nodeList1.item(j), XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodeList2 = (NodeList) result2;
    List<String> binList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {
        binList.add(nodeList2.item(j).getNodeValue());
    }
    binDataList.add(binList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, But this won't work.

Comment: First second expression should be _//*/text()_ because if you give _*/text()_ it will be empty.

Comment: output for this change [ ,  , 100510,  , LOCAL CARD,  ,  ,  , , UNITED KINGDOM, ,  , GB,  , GBR,  , 826,  , NULL, , NULL, , NULL,  , NULL, 
    , 
    , 
        , 100515,  , LOCAL CARD,  , , ,  , NORWAY, ,  , NO,  , NOR, , 578, , NULL,  , NULL,  , NULL,  , NULL, 
    , 
    , 
        , 103753,   , LOCAL CARD,  , I&M BANK, , DEBIT,  , PREPAID, 
        , KENYA,  ,  , KE, , KEN,  , 404, ,  , , NULL, , NULL, 
    , 
    , 
        , 104001,  , LOCAL CARD,  , LUXURY JEWELLERY CLASS (LJC) - TDFS,  ,  ,  , CANADA,  , , CA,  , CAN,  , 124,   ,    ,    , 
        , 
    , 
]

Comment: So again its a single list.

Comment: Thanks @har07 for your effort.

Comment: @AG what I missed is the XPath should be evaluated relative to current item of `nodeList1`, probably like this : `xPathExpression2.evaluate(nodeList1.item(j), XPathConstants.NODESET)`

Comment: Better to use SAX parser for such thing.